# VB: ArrayList with string as index (key)

Tags: .net, vb.net

Is there a way to insert values into an arraylist and assign them with a string as key/index?

I tried:

```
arrayList.Insert("abc", "value123")
```

Comment: Have you tried using Dictionary type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there is no need to use an `ArrayList` anymore. Use a typed `List(Of T)` to avoid that you   always have to cast the objects which is also more error-prone.

In this case it seems that you actually need a `Dictionary(Of String, String)`:

```
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
dict.Add("abc", "value123")
```

Now you can access it by key very fast:

```
Dim value As String = dict("abc") ' exception if it doesnt contain this key '
```

Note that the keys must be unique and that you can use `TryGetValue` or `ContainsKey` to check whether or not it contains the key to avoid the exception.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a StringDictionary

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.stringdictionary.add(v=vs.110).aspx

```
  Dim myCol As New StringDictionary()
  myCol.Add("red", "rojo")
```